# static method call stack in java

Tags: java, memory, static-methods, callstack

Let say I have a code :

```
public static int process(customObject obj){
// some process and then return some count
return obj.getCount();
}
```

If two methods from two different class call `process` method at the exactly same time. 
How java will manage the call stack in this case?

- Will there be only one call stack for `process` and  calling method will share this stack?
- Will there two call stack for `process` and calling method will have their own copy of the stack?

If **case-1**, how will java know what result it should return to which calling method (how will this behavior change in multi-thread environment )?

**Note : CustomObject is a parent Type, it can have multiple implemented types.**

Comment: Every thread has its own stack. You need to make sure your code is thread safe, if it gets used by multiple threads. `static` has nothing to do with either of these.

Comment: Your last edit makes no sense. You start by talking about calling a method at the same time. Thus you are in a multithread environment. A single thread cannot do more than one thing "at the same time".

Comment: Your static method in the current form does not store anything on the stack anyway.

Comment: to add to @Thilo 's comment, if you declare primitives and object assignments they will be copied across threads, but objects will be stored in the heap (thus not duplicated)

Comment: `obj` is passed in on the stack. So if you have two different threads passing in two different `obj`, these do not conflict. But two threads could also pass in the same `obj`. The object instance itself lives on the shared heap. Only the variable/pointer/reference to that is on the stack.

Comment: `static` really does not make a difference here. The only difference is that there is no `this` in a `static` method (but you are not using that here). The type of `customObject` also does not matter, really.

Comment: but if you save the method parameter (obj) as a static variable of that particular class, it will get mixed up between threads/calls

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea No, That's not the case.

Comment: I know, just wanted to illustrate when your concern will be an actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

The stack is per thread not class/object/method...

*Will there be only one call stack for process and calling method will share this stack?* - no, there will be 2

*Will there two call stack for process and calling method will have their own copy of the stack?* - each thread has one stack, but **obj** will be the same object for both as it's stored in the heap (considering that you will use the same obj as parameter)

Comment: `obj` could also be two different objects. Depends on what the callers pass in.

Comment: so, if the method is `static` or not, every caller will have it's own copy of that method?

Comment: What do you mean by copy? The bytecode for the method exists only once. But local variables and parameters (like your `obj`) are passed in using the stack (of which each thread has their own).

Comment: I see where you are going, yes, regardless if the method is static or not, same rules apply (primitives and references are copied for each stack/stacktrace/thread, objects are not)

Comment: if `TypeA` and `TypeB` has different values for `count` and were passed to `process` by different methods , so is there any chance that caller methods may receive count of any Type regardless what Type they have passed?

Comment: no, the "state" is saved on the stack, so they won't get mixed up (regardless if the method is static), hope I understood correctly

Comment: Method = Recipe. Stack = Kitchen. Thread = You and Me. We both have the same recipe cooking the same food in our own kitchen. Will my cutting board suddenly appear in your kitchen because we are cooking at the same time? No, of course not. Will we get into trouble if the recipe demands to use the same item that we need to share - yes, shared resources are when you need thread safety.